# Using the quill logging system with eclipse and getting false errors (undefined symbol)

Tags: c++, c++17, eclipse-cdt

I am working on a project and pulling the quill logging system (https://github.com/odygrd/quill) in.  I've got it working exactly as I want it, and it builds just fine, with nary a warning to be seen.  However, Eclipse doesn't seem to be happy:

[image: Eclipse errors]

The specific error is "Symbol 'MacroMetadata' could not be resolved".

However, in addition to building OK I can even hit F3 down into the code and end up in MacroMetadata.h where, not surprisingly, it is defined.

Additional details:

- Our project is a CMake-based, Linux application.
- We have quill installed on the machine and are calling "find_package(quill REQUIRED)" from within the CMakeLists.txt file.
- We're using C++17, the minimum supported by quill.
- Eclipse is version 2020-12 (4.18.0).  If a newer version would fix this I'd be interested to know, but we may or may not be able to upgrade, so workarounds would still be appreciated.

I really do not want to entirely disable the undefined symbol error within Eclipse, but I cant have errors popping up throughout the entire code base, either.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

I have already tried the following:

1. Wrapping the quill #define in our own #define with a comment to suppress the error.  However, Eclipse handles this error suppression line by line ignoring any code substitution.  I.E.

`#define _QUILL_LOG_ERROR(logger, fmt, ...) QUILL_LOG_ERROR(logger, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__) /* @suppress("Symbol is not resolved") */`

2. Tried wrapping the quill #define in a global function (lead wants to keep any wrapping very simple, header file only).  However, under the hood quill is defining a function within the macro expansion, which then becomes an issue for passing a parameter through ("use of parameter from containing function").
3. As well as playing a variety of games with the Eclipse indexer, including the MacroMetadata.h file directly, etc.  None of which made any difference.

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from verifying whether your issue can be reproduced in the current Eclipse version?

Comment: @howlger Nothing, except that I'm not sure how useful it would be (other than to verify that it has been fixed...).  This is the version that my company is using and I'm not likely to be able to change it (the joys of a large corp).

Comment: If you knew, then you would have a reason to ask your company for an update. In this case you could search for the issue if you are interested in the details (sometimes you can find a workaround in the comments of the issue). Independent from that, your company should update sooner for security reasons.